# Why does a SQL Server string output parameter return 0 on an EF ExecuteSqlCommand call?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this code in C# and I want to use a string `sReturn` as output parameter in my code.

```
var sReturn = new SqlParameter();
sReturn.ParameterName = "@Return";
sReturn.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
sReturn.Size = 300;
sReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

string query = "exec @Return = sqlServerProcedure @id, @dateBegin, @dateEnd";

_context.Database.CommandTimeout = timeout;
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
            (query, sReturn,
                new SqlParameter("@id", id),
                new SqlParameter("@dateBegin", dateBegin),
                new SqlParameter("@dateEnd", dateEnd) );
 return sReturn.Value;
```

`sReturn` is always returning 0.

Procedure is something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].sqlServerProcedure 
     (@dateBegin DATETIME,
      @dateEnd DATETIME,
      @id NUMERIC)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 'some random message'
END
```

Why is it always returning 0?

Comment: My question is why do this a sql command. Can you change the command type to stored procedure?

Comment: Did you perform any [research](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/stored-procedure-with-input-and-output-parameter-using-entity-framework-in-asp-m/)?

Comment: the zero means that no row affected

Comment: The 0 is the return value of the stored procedure, and 0 indicates success.  As @Vinit below answered correctly, the string value is returned in a result set, and can be read with ExecuteReader(), or, since there is only one row and one column, with ExecuteScalar().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the SQL Server procedure and the calling of it in `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

You have to do this in C#:

```
string query = "exec sqlServerProcedure @id, @dateBegin, @dateEnd, @Return OUTPUT";
```

In SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].sqlServerProcedure 
    (@dateBegin DATETIME,
     @dateEnd DATETIME,
     @id NUMERIC,
     @Return VARCHAR(300) OUTPUT)
```

Answer (score 3):

You really don't need to declare @return parameter, if you are expecting a single value from procedure, use `ExecuteScalar()` method of SQL `command`.

Also you can use stored procedure type instead of inline SQL query. Your ADO.net code will look like below, no changes in stored procedure.

```
_context.Database.Connection.Open();
var cmd = _context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = timeout;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sqlServerProcedure";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateBegin", dateBegin));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateEnd", dateEnd));
var result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: `_context.Database` is not `DbCommand` and has no `ExecuteScalar` method (and other properties shown).

Comment: _context.database dont have a executeScalar method

Comment: @IvanStoev - u r right, i overlooked that it was an entity database context and not SQL command. your answer should be the solution.

Comment: @Vinit Yeah, the ORMs with their limitations :)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - thanks! good to know to this approach :)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Just out of curiosity, what's the benefit of doing all that instead of using the EF "intended" one-liner? After all the question is tagged `entity-framework`, right?  And your edit is bypassing the EF at all. And btw, is missing `try/finally` to `Close` the connection that you `Open` at the beginning - things that EF normally handles automatically for you.

Comment: @IvanStoev  You would normally use this pattern only for ADO.NET scenarios that aren't handled by EF's convenience methods.  The point is to demonstrate how to "drop down" from the EF layer to the ADO.NET layer underneath, when you need the full functionality of your DbConnection.  And EF will close the connection for you on DbContext.Dispose.  The Database.Connection.Open() just prevents EF from opening and closing the connection multiple times over the lifecycle of the DbContext.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Of course the connection is available. Still manually opening it and not closing it changes the default EF behavior. Anyway, as I said, I was just curious why you are so involved with (insist on) using plain ADO.NET with EF (looking at your recent posts and now this edit). Not that using any kind of SQL is not against core EF principles :) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) contains the following:

> @return_status
>   Is an optional integer variable that stores the return status of a module. This variable must be declared in the batch, stored procedure, or function before it is used in an EXECUTE statement.
>
> When used to invoke a scalar-valued user-defined function, the @return_status variable can be of any scalar data type.

Since you are invoking a stored procedure (not scalar-valued function), the return value is 0 (success) converted to string.

If you were using ADO.NET, then you could use `ExecuteScalar` as mentioned in another answer. However EF6 `ExecuteSqlCommand` method is equivalent of the ADO.NET `ExecuteNonQuery` and cannot be used to retrieve the returned single row single column *record set*.

The easiest way to execute your stored procedure and get the desired string result in EF6 is to use the combination of EF `SqlQuery<string>` method and LINQ `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var returnValue = _context.Database
    .SqlQuery<string>("sqlServerProcedure @p0, @p1, @p2", dateBegin, dateEnd, id)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```